# Document Information Panel (Infopath 2007 .xsn) crashes Word 2010 when creating an instance of the content type, any idea why?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, content-type, word, document-info-panel

My problem seems to be that whenever I create an instance of a document content type it seems to crash Word 2010, I've tested it on another PC with Word 2007 installed and it opens the document just fine with the document information panel (DIP) fully working.

For compatibility reasons I will need to use it in Word 2007, but in case there's ever an upgrade I would like to know I won't have to redo everything.

I'm using Infopath .xsn 2007 format to create the DIP but in Infopath 2010 (don't know if this is part of the issue?), as .xsn 2010 format does not work on Word 2007.

I'm using SharePoint Enterprise Server 2010, the site this is used on is a team site, and the document content types' template is a .docx which opens absolutely fine with quick parts in place.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.